# Cannot save as root with tramp: “Unlocking file: Permission denied”

Tags: tramp, emacs27, permissions

I'm using Emacs 27.1 in the terminal with tramp version 2.4.3.27.1. This is on a remote server over SSH.

I can load files as root using tramp paths such as: `/sudo:root@hostname:/etc/hosts` or `/sudo::/tmp/test`, but when I try to write the buffer I always get an error such as:

```
Unlocking file Permission denied /sudo:root@hostname:/tmp/test
```

`*Messages*` shows:

```
Saving file /sudo:root@hostname:/tmp/test...
tramp-signal-hook-function: Unlocking file Permission denied /sudo:root@hostname:/tmp/test
```

Emacs actually writes (or attempts to write) the buffer as my user rather than root. For existing files owned by root no changes are made, but where my user has permissions the file is updated or created with my user and group.

I have confirmed that Tramp is definitely reading the files as root, as I have tested it on existing paths only accessible to root. When trying to write these, I get the same error as above but of course no changes are made to the file.

It's possible the problem began after upgrading Ubuntu packages a couple of days ago, but I can't be certain.

What can I try to get back the ability to write files as root?

Comment: I vaguely remember that there was such a problem in Tramp, but I cannot find it. Does it help to upgrade to the recent Tramp package in GNU ELPA? It is 2.6.1.2.

Comment: Thanks, upgrading Tamp to 2.6 did not solve the issue. Deleting my config and reinstalling Emacs did not help either. I think there must be something interfering at a lower level of the server.

Comment: If you need further help in analysis, pls send a message to the `tramp-devel@gnu.org` ML.